# visual key pad with PHP

Tags: php

I was wondering how to create visual key pad with PHP.

I am talking about normal kepad only alphabettical letters.

[image]

Comment: Eleven. (That makes about as much sense as your question.)

Comment: @middaparka: 42, not eleven ;-)

Comment: I'd say 42... makes total sense to me...

Comment: I have revised it to simple english and I hope you guys now ok

Comment: Dont look at the layout please this is something different. and also nothing to so with actual keypad layout.

Comment: php is a server-side language. It can't display anything nor interact with user. you need something browser-specific for this

Comment: @Daniel: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTZ

Comment: @Rocket - I was being facetious lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick search on Google and found a bunch of results here:
[jQuery visual keyboard](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20visual%20keyboard&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)

Looks like there are a bunch of jQuery (javascript) methods to do this, combined with some CSS and HTML.  Keep in mind that PHP is not something the user ever sees, it is strcitly server side.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can modify this Javascript Virtual Keyboard, removing the keys you don't want:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/jsvk.aspx

Or this one: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/jvk.aspx